# Error: Too many query locator rows: 10001

Tags: apex, batch

I have batchable apex that is throwing the Too Many Query Locator Rows error:

```
Global Class FocusDomainBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.allowsCallouts
    {
        global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
        {
            String query = 'Select id,name from Domain_Stats__c';
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);    
        }


global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
    {
        try
        {
           List <Focus_Domain_Stats__c> allDomains = scope;          
           List <string> web = new List <string>();
```

There are more than 10k Domain_Stats__c records, but I was under the impression that in batchable that was ok?

It is being called by :

```
Public Class FocusDomainStatsSchedulable implements Schedulable 
{
    Public void execute(SchedulableContext SC)
    {
        try
        {
           if(!Test.isRunningTest())
           {
                FocusDomainBatch fd = new FocusDomainBatch();
                Database.executeBatch(fd,5);
           }

         } 
         Catch(exception e)
         {
             throw e;
         }
    }
}
```

Here is the test class that is failing:

```
@IsTest(seealldata=true)

    Public Class TestFocusDomainBatch
    {

    Static testMethod void TestFocusDomainBatch ()
    {               

        Test.StartTest();

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator1());
        FocusDomainBatch fb = new FocusDomainBatch(); 
        Date lastMonth = Date.Today().addMonths(-6);
        fb.start(null); //Failing here
        fb.finish(null);
        //List<Focus_Product__c> fpContacts = [select id,contact__c from Focus_Product__c where createddate > :lastmonth and contact__C <> null limit 1];
        //List<Focus_Product__c> fpLeads = [select id,contact__c from Focus_Product__c where createddate > :lastmonth and contact__C <> null limit 1];        

        List <Lead> allLeads = [Select Id, name, HG_Focus_Sign_Up_Date__c, website from Lead where createddate > :lastMonth and isConverted = false and Focus_Sign_Up_Date__c <> null limit 1];
        List <Contact> allContacts = [Select Id, name, HG_Focus_Sign_Up_Date__c, account.website from contact where createddate > :lastMonth and Focus_Sign_Up_Date__c <> null limit 1]; 
        List<string> webs = new List<string>();
        if(allLeads.size() > 0)
            webs.add(allLeads[0].webSite);
        if(allContacts.size() > 0)
            webs.add(allContacts[0].account.webSite);
        //database.executebatch(fb);
        fb.execute(null,[Select id,name, First_user_sign_up_date__c, Total_Users__c, New_Users_In_Last_Month__c, Avg_Fvrt_Pro_Per_User__c, Users_with_zero_fvrts__c, Users_with_2_or_less_fvrts__c, Average_daily_queries__c, Average_monthly_queries__c, Total_current_month_queries__c, Total_Queries__c from Focus_Domain_Stats__c where name in :webs]);
        Test.StopTest();

    }
```

Comment: yes but upper limit is 50 million. so you should check too. Also you are sure you are getting error here?

Comment: You must re-query for them somewhere else. The code you have posted should give you no issue.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I updated the question to show more detail.

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with the solution but you should remove your `Test.isRunningTest` check. Never use it if you can avoid it!

Comment: updated to show the test class. It is failing where it says fb.start(null)

Comment: @AdrianLarson it looks like the lead and contact lists have limit 1 in them, so I dont think that is the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you should really test a batch is by calling `Database.executeBatch`. Don't call `start` and `execute` directly.

You should also test without `SeeAllData`. You should never use `SeeAllData` unless it's your only choice. There are many reasons why it's bad practice to unit test against existing data. Unit tests will not perform the same in your sandboxes as your staging/production environments. Your tests will run *significantly* slower. You have a lot less control over what you're actually testing.

Take a look at [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_testing) (specifically the *Testing Batch Apex* section). You need to make sure you get at most one `execute` block, which effectively limits you to 200 records.

```
static testMethod void testMyBatch()
{
    // setup data for your batch to process
    // make sure it's less than 200 records
    // you can only call the execute method once!

    Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch());
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert on results
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had removed the focus part before (was trying to clean up).

Comment: @Justin I'm surprised I can't find a better resource for why data silos are so important in unit testing for `Apex`...but you should definitely start by removing `SeeAllData` and trying to create your own data for the test.

Comment: Thanks, Ill give that a shot. In this case, I think it was because the class uses a callout that pulls in login credentials from a custom setting, so it is doing a SOQL to get those.

Comment: I don't recall where I read about SeeAllData = false as best practice, but the reason is simple: relying on production data can cause your unit tests to fail arbitrarily simply because a record was created, updated, or deleted. It makes for very fragile tests.

Comment: Right, I have a good understanding myself. It would be nice if we had something more comprehensive to point to. I might create a wiki about it for posterity. @sfdcfox

Comment: there are some occasions where the `start()` and `execute()` must be called individually (or at least when [I blogged about it](http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/06/18/batchable-class-test-data-callouts-how-to-test/)).

Comment: @cropredy Ah, but it seems this `start` block does not contain any callouts. That looks like the only case you outlined?

Comment: I was more editorializing on your first sentence in the answer.  Not about this specific OP.   :-)

Comment: Could it be that only in tests can a database.getQueryLocator not return more than 10k? 

Removing the see all data issue *should* fix that then...

Comment: @Justin Maybe so. You certainly can't *create* 10k records in a unit test. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson  I created a new test class that uses database.executeBatch which works wonderfully in sandbox, but when I deployed to prod I am getting "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out"... but again... only in production. In sandbox it works just fine... any ideas?

Comment: @Justin Sounds like a great *new* question. :)